# Deriving relationship using combinatorics and inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Given $N$ balls numbered from 1 to N and each ball is assigned some color in the range [1,N].

- $p_n$ - the number of permutations of these balls such that it has $n$ pairs of adjacent balls with the same color
- $q_n$ - the number of permutations of these balls such that it has at least n pairs of adjacent balls with the same color

What is the relation between $p$ and $q$?

I found the solution somewhere as

$$
q_n=\sum_{k=n}^{N-1}\binom kn p_k
$$
But I don't understand how?

Also

$$p_n=\sum_{k=n}^{N-1} (-1)^{k-n}\binom kn q_k$$

It was given that $p_n$ is derived from inclusion exclusion principle. Although i know what is inclusion exclusion principle, i still don't understand how is this derived?

Comment: Given $n$ balls [1,N]??

Comment: Did you intend that the balls are (in effect) Ball-1, Ball-2, ..., Ball-n?  Also, there does seem to be a discrepancy between your use of $n$ and $N$.  Also, how many different colors are used in the assignment of colors to balls, and how many balls are there for each such color?  It is a good idea to proofread your question before/after posting to check if the reviewer is going to have such questions.